# SwiftUI: custom alignment guide breakdown?

Tags: swiftui

I posted this question:

[SwiftUI: align views in different HStacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555356/swiftui-align-views-in-different-hstacks)

Solution provided works great.

I am trying to understand **why** in details.

Specifically:

How is it setting the guide to be to the left of the Text "Some Text"?

I would think this is the line that does it:

`Text("Some text").alignmentGuide(.myLeading) { $0[.leading] }`

Why is it that the guide doesn't get set to the left of the Image actually?

Is it because the Text view comes first in the view?

Why do I have to provide the guide to the container?

`VStack(alignment: .myLeading)`

Can somebody help me understand how to breakdown this flow so I can understand each step as it happens?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<10) {
            RowView(item: $0)
        }
    }
}

extension HorizontalAlignment {
   private enum MyLeadingAlignment: AlignmentID {
      static func defaultValue(in dimensions: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
         return dimensions[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
      }
   }
   static let myLeading = HorizontalAlignment(MyLeadingAlignment.self)
}

struct RowView: View {
    let item: Int
    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .myLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("item: \(item)")
                Text("Some text")
                    .alignmentGuide(.myLeading) { $0[.leading] } // << here !!
                Spacer()
            }
            Image(systemName: "squareshape.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .alignmentGuide(.myLeading) { $0[.leading] } // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give you many answers https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/

Comment: ok. Looks great. Thanks